# Gnome Oracles FCB with curses giving spells known

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, racial-traits

Gnome Oracles have the following favoured class bonus:

> Oracle: Treat the gnome's level as +1/2 higher for the purpose of determining the effects of the oracle's curse ability.

Some Oracle's curses give spells known at higher levels. For example the haunted curse:

> Haunted: Malevolent spirits follow you wherever you go, causing minor mishaps and strange occurrences (such as unexpected breezes, small objects moving on their own, and faint noises). Retrieving any stored item from your gear requires a standard action, unless it would normally take longer. Any item you drop lands 10 feet away from you in a random direction. Add mage hand and ghost sound to your list of spells known. At 5th level, add levitate and minor image to your list of spells known. **At 10th level, add telekinesis to your list of spells known.** At 15th level, add reverse gravity to your list of spells known.

Emphasis mine

A level 7 Gnome Oracle who took the favoured class bonus 6 times counts as level 10 for the effect of his curse. With the haunted curse that means he gets telekinesis as a spell known, which is normally a 5th level spell. The level 7 oracle has level 3 spells as his highest spell level.

Is telekinesis gained that way still a level 5 spell? Or is it of the highest level the oracle can cast when he gets it as a spell known?

Similar problems can arise with gnome oracles and the blackened curse.

I asked a [linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/can-you-have-spells-known-of-spell-levels-you-cant-cast-yet) here about whether it is possible to have spells known higher than the highest you can cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A level 7 [gnome](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/gnome) [oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle) that's picked at least 6 times the [gnome oracle favored class bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/gnome#TOC-Favored-Class-Options) does, indeed, count as a level 10 oracle for the [oracle curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses) haunted, and, at level 10, that oracle's curse adds the spell [*telekinesis*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinesis) to the oracle's spells known.

Nonetheless, the [*telekinesis*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinesis) spell itself is unchanged. The spell *telekinesis* remains a 5th-level spell so the level 7 oracle must still advance 3 more levels before the spell can be cast, but, in the meantime, as the spell's now on that oracle's spell list, such a gnome oracle can more easily activate any *divine [scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls) of telekinesis* he acquires (maybe from another oracle with the haunted oracle's curse?), and such a gnome oracle, were he lucky enough to get one, could activate a *[staff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/staves) of telekinesis* earlier than he otherwise could.

Answer (score 1):

You get the spell, as a level 5 one. As you are still only a level 7 Oracle you can't cast it (but you will as soon as you will be lvl 10).

Yes, this gnome favoured class bonus is pretty useless with this oracle's curse. It happens.